# How to restore default setting in VS Code

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

I was playing with VS code settings (I wanted to explore VS Code) and suddenly the code editing got changed. Previously the code was more colourful and there were different colours for different keywords. Now my code is mostly white. Please help me to get back to default code formatting settings.[image: Here is a screenshot for reference]

Comment: Revert the settings or re-install VS Code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To revert the settings completely, open the settings JSON file by bringing up the command palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and running the command `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`. Delete everything in there and save the file.

However, you might just have switched to a different theme by accident. To check that, open the theme chooser (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd>) and try the other themes.